# Phpunit options doesnt work in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, windows-7, phpunit

When I run cmd from laravel main folder [options] doesn't work. I want to run only 2 test from one file and always when I write "phpunit --something" it just run tests. I'm using windows 7 cmd.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel you have to edit your `phpunit.xml` in your root folder.

Add an testsuite to this file like this or similar to this

```
<testsuite name="something">
    <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/something/*</directory>
</testsuite>
```

Now run

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite "something"
```

For specific functions use something like

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit --filter testFunction "tests/myfolder/MyTest.php"
// Format: vendor/bin/phpunit --filter {TestMethodName} {FilePath}
```

Comment: Doesnty work for me. When I write phpunit --filter it's just start testing, like "phpunit" command.